# magento frontend suddenly 503 - howto debug

Tags: php, magento, redis, http-status-code-503

I couldn't find a clear answer and I think a lot of people could have major advantages by knowing the answer to this..

So, last night when I was finished at work our development website worked like a charm. Nothing changed between then and this morning. But for some weird reason magento frontend now gives me a 503 error or a VERY long loadtime.

So I checked logs and such, and since I use redis cache and redis session cache I disabled those. I tried memcache and even the normal settings. Nothing seems to work.

Now how can I discover what is killing the website?

If this is a duplicate I'm sorry. Couldn't find a good answer.

EDIT: Forgot to mention, sometimes the homepage for example loads after a LONG load..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use some profiling tools to find where the app is slow.
In dev you could use blackfire or xdebug+kcachegrind
In prod blackfire or xhprof

Comment: I use blackfire allready. But when given a 503 blackfire also has a 503 so aborts the test.

I'll look into xhprof :)

Comment: can you reproduce it in dev env ?

Comment: Yeah, it is in dev envoirment. But the problem is. nothing changed between the time it worked and the time it started doing this.

Comment: xdebug + kcachegrind will do the trick then, youll find what piece of code is taking forever

Comment: I feel so stupid.. We got the IP from a source. but they blocked our ip.. Now they whitelisted it thankfully.